# Remove PPPOE layer from packet

Tags: c#, networking

I am using pcapdotnet's DLL in my application but because this project does not currently support PPPOE I would like to add the functionality myself. My problem is that I do not have a good understanding of packet structure and PPPOE packet structure. I do not know the best way to get started. I have taken the same packet with and without the PPPOE layer and I have writen the bytes into a text file. I would be grateful for some help on how to continue.

**This is the packet without PPPOE layer:**

0
48
136
21
69
131
0
24
231
253
174
161
8
0
69
0
0
83
39
63
64
0
128
6
222
170
79
176
27
47
211
174
182
45
0
21
130
204
202
187
11
119
220
8
22
31
128
24
1
2
145
161
0
0
1
1
8
10
14
58
64
121
0
213
181
165
51
51
49
32
80
97
115
115
119
111
114
100
32
114
101
113
117
105
114
101
100
32
102
111
114
32
106
97
110
13
10

**and this is the same packet with PPPOE layer:**

0
48
136
21
69
131
0
24
231
253
174
161
136
100
17
0
1
95
0
85
0
33
69
0
0
83
39
63
64
0
128
6
222
170
79
176
27
47
211
174
182
45
0
21
130
204
202
187
11
119
220
8
22
31
128
24
1
2
145
161
0
0
1
1
8
10
14
58
64
121
0
213
181
165
51
51
49
32
80
97
115
115
119
111
114
100
32
114
101
113
117
105
114
101
100
32
102
111
114
32
106
97
110
13
10

Comment: I already approach it in python and dpkt module, but interesting the way in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/ or http://www.wireshark.org/

They will give you insight on the packet structure and how you will be able to manually decode it yourself if require.